# Stop Email Clients from auto-linking/styling dates?

Tags: html-email, email-client

Is it possible to stop Email Clients (iPhone, Mail.app, Sparrow..) from auto-linking or otherwise changing the style of dates in an email.

I want to style date/timestamps in emails as a light unassuming gray - however most mail clients turn this into a link with the traditional underline/blue combo. I am interested in blocking this from the HTML side *if possible*.

Comment: Have you tried using !important on your styles?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the issue is that they change the style - you end up with blue underlined phone numbers, for example.

Some clients have a custom meta-tag to let you do this. e.g. for Mail.app and iOS:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

However, others don't. What you can do instead is add your own link and style that to appear exactly the same as the text around it.